# how to select similar words in Visual Studio Resharper plugin

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I want to **select similar** words in Visual Studio with `Resharper` plugin.

In `webStorm` or `phpStorm`, I can use `Alt`+`j` to select similar words, But in Visual Studio it's not working!

what is the shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

you can use CTRL+SHIFT+F7 for Highlight similar words in file for visual studio

refer [this](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206016289-Highlight-usages-of-selected-word) link

Comment: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206016289-Highlight-usages-of-selected-word

Comment: It;s just highlight the words